# in Wordpress: Adding a Manual exceprt hides the "show more" link in index page

Tags: wordpress

My site displays excerpts automatically just fine, But I want to add some other text in the excerpt of my post, I go to screen options -> check excerpt, and then in the excerpt window below the screen editor i type whatever i want.

However the problem is that after i save, the "read more" link in the main page disappears.

How can i edit the excerpt manually and still keep the "read more" link visible?

I have tried searching for the issue but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your functions.php

```
   function new_excerpt_more($more) {
   global $post;
   return '… <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . 'Read More &raquo;' . '</a>';
   }
   add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Here you are telling WordPress to remove the default more which looks like this: [...], and replace it with a link.

Comment: Hi newTag, when i added this code the post page stopped functioning, so i checked the functions.php file and it appears it already has this function. so the issue still remains. just to clarify more, the site already displays the "read more" just fine, but when i add an excerpt manually through the post editor, the "read more" link disappears.

Comment: @user3148931 Ok. Can you please go through this.. http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More and see if it helps..

Comment: Also check if your theme may be using <?php the_excerpt();?> instead of <?php the_content();?> in its template files. Simply edit the relevant template files and replace <?php the_excerpt();?> with <?php the_content();?>.

Comment: hey newTag, thanks for your help, I have read the article, and es indeed the theme is using <?php the_excerpt();?>, I've also tried adding a <!--more --> tag but it also didn't help.